# Interpolation between 3 variables and a value

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have a set of data including time and location `x` `y` `z` these data belong to a particle passing through a domain. I need to know the location at specific time.

According to the Matlab documentation:

> Vq = interp3(X,Y,Z,V,Xq,Yq,Zq) returns interpolated values of a
>   function of three variables at specific query points using linear
>   interpolation.

I need to know the `x` `y` `z` of particle at specific time. Is there any function for this job in MATLAB?

Is it okay to interpolate each location one by one? I mean interpolate between `t`-`x` `t`-`y` and `t`-`z`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're just after 3 1D interpolations assuming x, y and z are orthogonal components:

```
xi = interp1(T,X,ti)
yi = interp1(T,Y,ti)
zi = interp1(T,Z,ti)
```

where `ti` are the times you're looking to interpolate to, T, X, Y, Z are your full data vectors for each variable and `[xi,yi,zi]` form your interpolated points.

Comment: Is there really no other way to this? For example, is it possible to reduce the number of calls to the interp1 function by using the interp2 function?

Comment: @m_power maybe, why don't you test it and see. Just specify the indices of the second dimension as `1:3` and then interpolate to `1:3` i.e. you're interpolating between points in the second dimension, only in the first. I don't see why that wouldn't work.